# Canvas element: Image clicked

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, position

I want to know if the user clicked over an image drawed in a canvas. I click over the image but nothing happens. The alert isn't called. The last if condition never pass. Any idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <canvas id="game" height="500" width="700">
            </canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
        (function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('game'),
                context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                fps = 1,
                character = Image(),
                positions = [[125, 55], [480, 55], [125, 185], [480, 182], [125, 315], [480, 315]],
                random, x, y, xc, yc = null;

            canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                xc = event.screenX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                yc = event.screenY - canvas.offsetTop;

                if((xc >= x) && (xc <= (x + character.width)) && (yc >= y) && (yc <= (y + character.height))) {
                    alert('X = ' + x + 'Y = ' + y);
                }
            }, true);

            character.src = 'character.png';

            setInterval(function() {
                random = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));

                random = positions[random];
                x = random[0];
                y = random[1];

                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.drawImage(character, x, y);
            }, 1000 / fps);
        }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here.

First, your event code is broken `screenX` returns the mouse position relative to the *screen*, you need to use `clientX` or in IE `pageX` see [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos) for more information.

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // IE does not pass the event param!

    // you should use var infront of these local variables
    // otherwise you leak them into the global namespace
    // and you can even overwrite things there if you don't watch out
    var xc = (event.clientX ? event.clientX : pageX) - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var yc = (event.clientY ? event.clientY : pageY) - canvas.offsetTop;
```

Second, the code never runs in Chrome! It fails with `Uncaught TypeError: DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.` at line 15. You need to use the `new` keyword when creating the image, since it's not guaranteed otherwise, that the `Image()` will return a new instance.

```
...
context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
fps = 1,
character = new Image(),
...
```

Comment: The DOM error isn't happening here (FF 3.6). What's the difference between clientX and screenX? I will read the article, thank you.

Comment: Chrome gives me the error, it's not guaranteed that just calling the function will return a new image. Difference is that `screenX` starts at the top left of your screen. `clientX` starts at the top left of the web page, meaning that only the latter will give you the correct results in this case.

Comment: I didn't get the difference between web page and screen. i am going to read the article. Thank you.